# Google Calendar Api throwing error

Tags: php, google-calendar-api, google-api-php-client

> 1 . Deprecated: google-api-php-client's autoloader was moved to
>   vendor/autoload.php in 2.0.0. This redirect will be removed in 2.1.
>   Please adjust your code to use the new location. in
>   D:\wamp\www\api\Calendar_api\src\Google\autoload.php on line 19 2 .
>   Fatal error: Class 'Google_Service_Calendar' not found in
>   D:\wamp\www\api\quickstart.php on line 12

Comment: Possible duplicate of [google-api-php-client's autoloader deprecated](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29438895/google-api-php-clients-autoloader-deprecated)

Comment: Welcome to stack please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and please at least try to google your error message in the future.

Answer (score 0):

I changed require path to this it worked for me.
    **require_once '../src/Google/autoload.php';**